# Calculate Angle of outer Circle position to center with height of circle

Tags: geometry

[image]

I want to calculate the green marked angle $A$. I have the Circle Radius and the height of the orange line(the y-value).

I thought I can make use of
$$
A = \arctan\left(\frac{y_1 - y_2}{x_1 - x_2}\right)
$$
but for that i would need the x value of the intersection point of the red line with the circle. But i dont know how to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Simply, you are asking, given the circle has radius $r$, what is the coordinate at which the horizontal line $y=B$ intersects the circle.

Remember the equation of the circle is $x^2+y^2=r^2$, and so in your case, we must have $x^2 = r^2 - B^2$. Can you finish this?